# Sorting using the Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

Python SDK for Smartsheet API (latest versions)

Here's the scenario:
I have a large (over 3000 rows) sheet. New records are added (at the bottom) in batches (typically 100 - 150 rows at a time). 
There is a column with an identifier (not an auto-number). 
We would like to sort on the identifier.

This is easy but manual using the GUI. 
Since it is probable that a large portion of the rows will be affected, I suspect that this sorting may be something that hits or exceeds rate limits when done via the API.

Before I invest too much time in developing the solution, I'm looking for a sanity check on whether it will or might exceed those limits.

Thanks.

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is single-threaded and working with a single sheet, it's unlikely that you will encounter rate limiting. Also, the Python SDK automatically retries rate limit errors. (And the other SDKs will soon.)

Comment: Thanks Steve. Just what I was hoping to hear!